# Keep a sub view in the corner

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I tried to keep a sub view in the corner of a UIViewController by using auto-layout (Horizontal Space, and Vertical Space), but always causes error of missing constraints (like view need constrains for Width, Height). Could you explain me why?

[image]

Note: I am using XCode 5, iOS7

Comment: It would help to show the constraints logged and to describe the error... Is it a runtime or an Xcode error?

Comment: Thanks Wain, I just edited.

Comment: All the view knows is that it should be 50px from the top and 100px to the right, it doesn't know what size it should be ... constrain it to a width/height or to another superview edge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the green box you will need to place more constraints on it.  You already have the left and upper constraints.  However, you still need to make constraints for the width and the height.  At the bottom of the storyboard view where you selected the constraints you have, you will find another choice in that menu that says height and width.  Select them as well and you should be fine.  Views need at least four constraints so they know where to go!